# Group algebra is indecomposable for p-groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

> Let $k$ be a field of prime characteristic $p$, and let $G$ be a finite $p$-group. Show that the group algebra $k[G]$ is indecomposable as a $k[G]$ module, that is, if $V,W\subset $ are sub-left $k[G]$-modules, with 
>   $k[G]=V\oplus W$, then either $k[G]=V$ or $k[G]=W$.

Here are the only interesting things that I noted so far. If $\displaystyle t=\sum_{g\in G}g$, then $U=\{
\lambda t \ | \ \lambda\in k \}$, is a simple module of dimension 1 over $k$, thus it must be entirely contained in one of the two summands, say $V$. Then I notice that $W
\subset \{\sum_{g \in G} \lambda_{g}g \ | \ \sum\lambda_{g}=0 \}$. Also I see that $t^2=0$.

Comment: Show that $k [G]$ is a local ring, so there are no non-trivial idempotents.